# Google drive API delete file updates the last modified date

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, delete-file

There is a different behavior from Google Drive UI and Google Drive API, when removing a file.

Using Google Drive UI:

remove a file, it will go to trash folder and the Last Modified Date is still the same. (if user restore the file, still there is no change on last modified date)

Using Google Drive API:

delete a file, it will go to trash folder, BUT the Last Modified date is changed and if user restore the file, there will be a new modified date.

to me API behavior is more correct, because there is an action made to the file, therefore modified date should change, but how come Google UI doesn't change the Last Modified date ?

Thanks,

Comment: I am using Google API to integrate our software with google drive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does appear to be an inconsistency between the UI and the API, although what the correct behavior should be is debatable. I've reached out the engineering team to see if they can bring the two paths inline. In the meantime, you can trash a file without changing the modifiedDate by instead using a Files.patch() request and setting the modifiedDateBehavior parameter to "noChange":

```
PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/...?modifiedDateBehavior=noChange

{
 "labels": {
  "trashed": true
 }
}
```

Comment: I have already raised this an issue to google, thanks for your follow up and the workaround.